# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':notifee_react-native:compileDebugAidl'

Tags: android, react-native, build-tools

***I just want to get started, can someone help me?***

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':notifee_react-native:compileDebugAidl'.

> Installed Build Tools revision 33.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.

On Windows:
I think this has to do with
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\build-tools\33.0.0 only containing:

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                 
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                 
d-----         1/14/2023   2:52 PM                renderscript                                                         
-a----         1/14/2023   5:24 PM              0 listing.txt                                                          
-a----         1/14/2023   2:52 PM          18339 package.xml
```

And %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk\build-tools\33.0.1 containing:

```
    Directory: C:\Users\wardb\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\33.0.1


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                 
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                 
d-----         1/14/2023   2:58 PM                lib                                                                  
d-----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM                lib64                                                                
d-----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM                lld-bin                                                              
d-----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM                renderscript                                                         
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM        1686296 aapt.exe                                                             
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM        3924248 aapt2.exe                                                            
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM            343 aarch64-linux-android-ld.exe                                         
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM        3331352 aidl.exe                                                             
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM           3233 apksigner.bat                                                        
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM            343 arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe                                         
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM         253208 bcc_compat.exe                                                       
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM          15149 core-lambda-stubs.jar                                                
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM           3189 d8.bat                                                               
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM         965400 dexdump.exe                                                          
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM           3189 dx.bat                                                               
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM            343 i686-linux-android-ld.exe                                            
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM         852760 libbcc.dll                                                           
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM         513816 libbcinfo.dll                                                        
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM       17777944 libclang_android.dll                                                 
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM       27555608 libLLVM_android.dll                                                  
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM          81176 libwinpthread-1.dll                                                  
-a----         1/14/2023   5:25 PM              0 listing.txt                                                          
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM         274200 lld.exe                                                              
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM        1370392 llvm-rs-cc.exe                                                       
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM            343 mipsel-linux-android-ld.exe                                          
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM        2789358 NOTICE.txt                                                           
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM          18343 package.xml                                                          
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM             17 runtime.properties                                                   
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM             63 source.properties                                                    
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM        1632536 split-select.exe                                                     
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM            343 x86_64-linux-android-ld.exe                                          
-a----        12/13/2022   9:19 PM         837912 zipalign.exe
```

android\build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.1"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "PiekverbruikMonitor",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@notifee/react-native": "^7.3.0",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

[image: Android SDK manager]

Error occurs when running: npx react-native run-android

```
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 3 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :notifee_react-native
:notifee_react-native @notifee/react-native found at C:\Projects\PiekverbruikMonitor\node_modules\@notifee\react-native
:notifee_react-native package.json found at C:\Projects\PiekverbruikMonitor\node_modules\@notifee\react-native\package.json
:notifee_react-native:version set from package.json: 7.3.0 (7,3,0 - 7003000)
:notifee_react-native:android.compileSdk using custom value: 33
:notifee_react-native:android.targetSdk using custom value: 33
:notifee_react-native:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:notifee_react-native:reactNativeAndroidDir C:\Projects\PiekverbruikMonitor\node_modules\react-native\android
WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33

This Android Gradle plugin (7.2.1) was tested up to compileSdk = 32

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33
WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33

This Android Gradle plugin (7.2.1) was tested up to compileSdk = 32

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33
Observed package id 'system-images;android-33;google_apis;x86_64' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\wardb\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64-2' (Expected 'C:\Users\wardb\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64')
Build-tool 33.0.0 is missing AAPT at C:\Users\wardb\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\33.0.0\aapt.exe
Observed package id 'system-images;android-33;google_apis;x86_64' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\wardb\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64-2' (Expected 'C:\Users\wardb\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64')
Observed package id 'system-images;android-33;google_apis;x86_64' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\wardb\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64-2' (Expected 'C:\Users\wardb\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\x86_64')
Build-tool 33.0.0 is missing AAPT at C:\Users\wardb\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\33.0.0\aapt.exe

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':notifee_react-native:compileDebugAidl'.
> Installed Build Tools revision 33.0.0 is corrupted. Remove and install again using the SDK Manager.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 53s

    at makeError (C:\Projects\PiekverbruikMonitor\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Projects\PiekverbruikMonitor\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Projects\PiekverbruikMonitor\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Projects\PiekverbruikMonitor\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied the entire 33.0.1 to 33.0.0 and it seems to work idk why